# dovecot rhel 5 installation fails because of newer libraries

Tags: linux, redhat, dovecot, rpm, installation

to whom it may respond to, 
we are trying to install dovecot (dovecot-2.2.10-1_14.el5.x86_64) on a RHEL 5.4 server and we get the error :

```
[root@asgfkm /]# rpm -i dovecot-2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64.rpm
uyarý: dovecot-2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 66534c2b: NOKEY
hata: Failed dependencies:
        libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by dovecot-1:2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64
        libldap-2.3.so.0()(64bit) is needed by dovecot-1:2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64
        libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by dovecot-1:2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64
        libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by dovecot-1:2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64
        libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by dovecot-1:2.1.17-0_136.el5.x86_64
[root@asgfkm /]#
```

but when we try to install requested libraries, it conflicts with the never libraries :

```
uyarý: openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID e8562897: NOKEY
        openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64 paketi zaten yüklü (openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1.x86_64 sürümünden daha yeni)
```

this is happening with the other libraries also : libldap, libmysql, etc...

Do you recommend --force option to install it or is there any other proper way around ? 
Thank you for your time,

Comment: You have some packages on your system which aren't intended for RHEL 5. Try `yum distro-sync` to repair your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> openssl-1.0.0-20.**el6**.x86_64 paketi zaten yüklü (openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1.x86_64 sürümünden daha yeni)
> ```

looks like you mixed packages from EL6.

also your dovecot is dovecot-**2.2**.10-1_14.el5.x86_64 or dovecot-**2.1**.17-0_136.el5.x86_64.rpm ??

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes , you are right, but the problem went on with the el5 packages also. The server has upper versions of all the dependencies. We somehow setup the rpms using force , it worked but garbaged the rpm dict.